# How to split Python views in bottle.py

Tags: python, bottle

I currently have a big file `server.py` containing all my bottle functions for routing. My application could be divided into 3 applications: news, forum, and blog.

I would know there is **a good way** to split my big file into 4 parts: news functions, forum functions, blog functions and common utilities (decorators, text formatting and others).

My current approach is to split my functions into 5 files : `server.py`, `blog.py`, `admin.py`, `news.py` and `utils.py`. `server.py` just contains the `bottle.run()` and import all others views.

Is it the good way? Is there any way to load/import functions automatically **WITHOUT** an `import *`.

Comment: *'load/import functions automatically WITHOUT an `import *`'* No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from blog import blogRoute
from admin import adminRoute
from news import newsRoute
from utils import utilsRoute
botapp = bottle.app()
for approute in (blogRoute, adminRoute, newsRoute, utilsRoute):
    botapp.merge(approute)
```

And in each of your python files, you just need this at the top: `blog.py` for example

```
from bottle import Bottle
blogRoute = Bottle()
```